# Android Error: Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'. > Process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

---

I am getting the above error when attempting to run a pre-made example project for a library i am attempting to use. This project uses the Android NDK.

- I installed the latest Java version, Android NDK and Android SDK. I have added their respective directories to my Path variable.
- Cygwin is installed
- Using Windows 7 and Android Studio

---

I have added the NDK directory to local.properties, in the same format as the SDK directory:

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Dylan\\Documents\\android-ndk-r10d

sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Dylan\\Documents\\sdk
```

---

This is where I *believe* Gradle fails:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}
```

Comment: Check out : https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-ndk-with-android-studio

Comment: Did you try to run the `ndk-build` manually? If so, what is the output?

Comment: Run `ndk-build.cmd` manually from the root of your project to get the full error message (not only ndk-build return code). You can also get it from the messages view and the gradle console.

Comment: This is the result @ph0b

C:\Users\Dylan\Downloads\SuperpoweredSDK\SuperpoweredSDK\
Android\CrossExample>ndk-build.cmd

'"C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\android-ndk-r10d\prebuilt/windows/bin/make.exe"' is not recognized as an i
nternal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @super-qua couldn't link both of you in one comment

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the ndk under windows, but the path to the make.exe seems wrong. Is there a make.exe present under `prebuilt\windows\bin`?

Comment: There is not a make.exe present under that directory, @super-qua [here](http://postimg.org/image/ha3s9xzqp/) is a link to an image of that folder

Comment: if make.exe isn't there, that means that your ndk hasn't been fully extracted. Launch the extractor again or do it manually using 7-zip.

Comment: @phob thank you! I extracted it again and it added the files I was missing. After fixing a few other issues, the NDK finally works!